# Splitting with the first occurrence of a character

Tags: regex, split

I want to match the first colon `:` of this string (in R):

`Ireland: Emergency Service Medal: Defence Forces`

How to achieve this?

I tried many options from various questions here on StackExchange, but they always point to *both* colons. For example:

`:(?=.*)`

or:

`(?<=.+?):(?=.+)`

The following matches *everything up to the first colon*; but I only want the first colon, nothing before and nothing after that:

`^([^:]*?)\s*:\s*`

Comment: With a perl like pattern, you can use `^[^:]+\K:`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thank you - perfect solution. Do you want to post it as a full-fledged response so that I can 'accept' it?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the first colon? I doubt you want to extract it. Replace/remove? Then it is still the same as matching *everything up to the first colon*: replace `^([^:]*):` with `$1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I want to use it as a separator.

Comment: Then there is nothing easier, match and capture with `^([^:]*):(.*)` / `^([^:]*):([\s\S]*)` / `(?s)^([^:]*):(.*)`. See [Splitting string from the first occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131195), [How to split a string on the first occurrence of one of multiple substrings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527374). No regex required in .NET code, see [Split string based on the first occurrence of the character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519548) (although [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178533))...

Comment: `^([^:]+):(.*)` you wil have $1 and $2 when you do a regex replace

Comment: What is your environment, programming language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you for the three solutions - strangely, none of them worked for me with `separate()`in `R` - the columns that I want to separate into are just empty with your three solutions... But anyway, the solution by @Thefourthbird worked well (`^[^:]+\K:`).

Comment: Ok, in R, you need to use `extract`, not `separate`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58206257/separate-character-string-at-first-digit-with-in-the-string/58492154#58492154